# android O not receiving FCM push messaging while phone is in sleep mode

Tags: android, background, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-7.0-nougat

I am using FCM for push messaging. I did not getting FCM notification if application is closed by user in android Noughat OS.

If user not close app, push notification works fine.

also if user add application in **protected app** from **setting->protected apps** app works even in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, you need the settings as below

> Settings->Notification->App->On the lock screen

It should not be do not show at all. By default it is always hide sensitive notification, hence if notify not defined as sensitive, will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have tried with notification setting but not getting FCM notification while app is in background